# What is a fair distance for a top of the line sprinter and marathoner to compete on?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, sprinting

Consider Eliud Kipchoge and Usain Bolt in their prime. Both amazing runners with vastly different trained areas of experience.

Bolt has an amazing anaerobic system for short distances and weights ~200lbs of muscles, and Kipchoge an unbeatable aerobic system at a light 135lbs.

Kipchoge would undeniably win a 10k race, Bolt could smoke Kipchoge at anything under 200m.

The question is, at what distance would it be a fair fight where some runs Bolt would win the other Kipchoge? It's really a question of what distance is evenly matched between aerobic and anaerobic systems and I bet it's a lot shorter than most realize.

Comment: I am migrating this to the Sports site. However, it may be likely closed as opinion based unless you can modify it to be looking more for the research and actual comparisons rather than just what people think.